# Is there anyway to programmatically fetch a zipball of private github repo?

Tags: git, oauth, github, repository

We got a necessity to fetch a zipball of a private repo. For public ones it's pretty easy either through GitHub API or manually (*https://github.com/user/repo/zipball/master*). But what about private repos? Not exactly obvious how to do it even having oAuth token.

Comment: what is this "Zipball" can you please give me little more description.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**New Alternative**

Because the given accepted answer does not work anymore, I thought I would explain how I was able to do it with the new changes in the github API.

**The new Download Api Link**

First, I found information about downloading the archive here:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link

**Public Repo**

If it's a public repo then it is very easy... you can do:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/pengwynn/octokit/tarball > octokit.tar.gz
```

**Private Repo**

If it's it is a private repo, you need to create an oAuth token by going to your settings and then selecting "Developer settings" / "[Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)".
I created a personal token.

Then using the instructions on the following page I found out how to get private repo that you have permission to:
https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

**Full Code**

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: token ab499f3b..." \
-L https://api.github.com/repos/godzilla/my_priv_repo/tarball > wut.tar.gz
```

Be sure to replace `ab499f3b...` with your actual token.

Comment: The `-L` before the url is what I was missing... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This no longer works.

---

with CURL:

```bash
curl -L -F "login=$USER" -F "token=$TOKEN" https://github.com/$USER/$REPO/$PKGTYPE/$BRANCHorTAG
```

where `$TOKEN` is the API token on your github profile, not an oAuth2 token used for communicating with the APIv3.

`$USER` is the user account the token is connected with, not necessarily the organization/other user the repo belongs to. Second Instance of `$USER` is the user/account the repo is.

`$REPO` is the name of the private repository

`$PKGTYPE` is tarball or zipball
and `$BRANCHorTAG` is a branch, like master, or a tag name for a commit.

The first instance of `$USER` must have access to the repo belonging to the second instance of `$USER`.

I could not find this documented ANYWHERE, so I also have a little write up about it if you want anything more detailed.

Comment: Not sure if this works anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418596/cant-find-api-token-in-github

Comment: This is definitely not working anymore. Generates "Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub". I think you should use api.github.com but then the URL is not found

Comment: still works, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68800637/5535820

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and this worked for me (as of Feb 2015):

```bash
curl -O -J -L -u $YOUROAUTHKEY:x-oauth-basic https://github.com/$USER/$REPO/archive/master.zip
```

The oAuth as a header solutions didn't work for me but what worked was stuffing the key into the username and specifying type. It then gave a 302 to redirect with the proper link.

Verbose command really helped me troubleshoot whether the credentials I was using were being accepted or not (404 vs 401)

Answer (score 2):

cURL which allows for HTTP header and request parameter manipulation. For example:

curl -L 
-H "Authorization: token $TOKEN"  
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/zipball --output hello.tar.zip

OR

curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/zipball?access_token=$TOKEN --output hello.tar.zip

Comment: Must specify access token via Authorization header!

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have a problem getting a zipball from the private repos for download.  I use the same format you have specified and it works perfectly.

I use OAuth2 to get the repositories but I build the link for the zip ball using the format you have given.  [Here is the application](https://github.com/jjNford/github-repositories) I do this in.

If you are looking to get an OAuth2 token, just use the [GitHubt API v3](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) format, it is pretty simple.  Although this doesn't fit your problem exactly :

[This](https://github.com/jjNford/oauth2-chrome-extension/tree/github) is how I get an OAuth2 token from GitHub for [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgekomkdphbcbfpnfjgcmjnnhfikinmn)

**UPDATE**

@jayarjo [I build the URL here on line 202](https://github.com/jjNford/github-repositories/blob/ce7f3fc70e95a9c2123e5efbb454b5333e82450a/js/repos.js#L202). I just build the URL like the one you specified, the OAuth2 token isn't even used for it.  All my token allows me to do is fetch all the users private data before I create the markup.  But it works with no problem...

I think the reason I am actually able to download the zipball is because the URL is actually to https://github.com/* and because I am currently signed in because of the OAuth2 I have permission to get to that URL - where as it sounds like you don't so you get a 404 error.

You may try sending a request to the page and if you get an error response prompt the user to login first, then when you request the zipball you should get it no problem.

Comment: Weird... I get "not found" error every time I try. Also when using the same format I have specified not sure where to place the token there?.. Can you link specific line of code where you do this?

Comment: @jayarjo Updated my answer - essentially the user must be logged in for the URL to be available to them.  Then you won't get a 404

Comment: But I fetch the token (I mean I have it the moment I try that url). But is this all you do and it works? Maybe I overlook something simple here...

Comment: @jayarjo - I think your missing what I am saying.  Because the user has to authorized their application, they have to signed into GitHub.  Thus they have access to the link.  If the user is not signed in, my links will not work either.  Again, the user must be logged into GitHub for your link to work (logged in the www.github.com - not your application).

Comment: But how do you get the token for the user, if user doesn't log in? I'm definitely missing something here...

Comment: @jayarjo By definition of OAUth2 the user must login to authorize the requesting application's permissions.  (http://oauth.net/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `api.github.com`, you can download the tarball/zipball from `github.com` directly:

(Token header `-H "Authorization: token $(yourToken)"`
can be omitted for public repo)

`curl -H "Authorization: token $(yourToken)" -o code.tar.gz -L https://github.com/$(username)/$(reponame)/tarball/$(branchName/TagName/hashValue)`

`curl -H "Authorization: token $(yourToken)" -o code.tar.gz -L https://github.com/$(username)/$(reponame)/archive/$(branchName/TagName/hashValue).tar.gz`

or for zipball

`curl -H "Authorization: token $(yourToken)" -o code.zip -L https://github.com/$(username)/$(reponame)/zipball/$(branchName/TagName/hashValue)`

`curl -H "Authorization: token $(yourToken)" -o code.zip -L https://github.com/$(username)/$(reponame)/archive/$(branchName/TagName/hashValue).zip`

You can generate a token according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796159

Answer (score 0):

You can use Basic Authentication or Token based method. See https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line for more details.