# can't find api token in Github

Tags: git, github

I've just installed GitExtension. Everything is configured. When I click on "Clone Github Repository", It opens a dialog box titled "Github Configuration" with following input boxes:
1. User
2. Password
3. APIToken
when I click on "Get Api Token" button, It takes me to my github.com profile. But there's no API key in there. I searched for an hour approximately, but couldn't figure out where to find it.

Note: It seems that GitHub recently changed their authentication method! I ain't sure what to do now. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

API Tokens are not supported by Github anymore
https://github.com/blog/1090-github-api-moving-on

You do not need the API Token to work with git.

It might be that GitExtension has not updated their authentication method. There is a command line Git tool for Windows, this will work:
http://msysgit.github.com/

Comment: Maybe just updating your current extension to the latest version would work, cause Github has updated their authentication process.

Comment: finally did that.. there's no other option left.

Comment: I think you're reading that post exactly wrong. They're saying you can no longer authenticate to the API via basic_auth, you must use a token, and you need to use the authorizations API to get one.

Answer (score 6):

API tokens seem to be back since May 2013: "[*Personal* API tokens](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens)"
(see your [setting page](https://github.com/settings/applications))

> The advantage to using a token over putting your password into a script is that a token can be revoked, and you can generate lots of them.