# Github curl how to include username and password

Tags: github-api

Hi all I have the following that works fine as long as I set the repository to public.

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/myrepos/myrepo/zipball > test.zp
```

But the repository is private.

Does anyone know how I can include my username and password into it?
Or better still have an example of how I can download it using a c# console app

Answer (score 1):

Following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960), the simplest solution is:

```
curl --user "caspyin:PASSWD" ...
```

But the best practice is to avoid using the password directly in a command, and use a [oauth token](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) instead ([associated to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/#creating-a-token)).

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <yourToken>" ...
```

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504791/is-there-anyway-to-programmatically-fetch-a-zipball-of-private-github-repo

Comment: @tramp-man yes, you would see the same header for authentication (with token)

Answer (score 1):

Create personal OAuth token from [Developer Settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Then

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <your token here>" \
-L https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner>/<repo-name>/tarball > repo.tar.gz
```

This is explained in this answer [stackoverflow.com/questions/9504791...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796159/4213854)